# D+ status in ps output

Tags: linux, ps

Is there any difference between D, Ds and D+ status of process from the ps output

```
$ ps -e -o pid,stat,comm,wchan=WIDE-WCHAN-COLUMN | grep D
  PID STAT COMMAND         WIDE-WCHAN-COLUMN
12987 D+   du              o2net_send_message_vec
```

I understand D stands for Disk Sleep. Want to know D+, Ds and what do they stand for?

Comment: The command `man ps` is your friend.

Comment: Yes. I should have done man ps thoroughly. I see the explanations there. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- `D` - uninterruptable sleep
- `+` - in foreground process group
- `s` - a session leader

These are for the BSD style `ps` command.